# How to send custom message using API?

Tags: php, api, sms-gateway

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://sms.webpal.com.np/base/smsapi/index.php?key=".$config['authkey']."&campaign=4498&routeid=22&type=text&contacts=".$receiver."&senderid=WebPal&msg=".$otp,
```

Result I am getting: 6547
I want this: Please use 6547 as otp to verify in Food App.

How to append this extra line of message on API call.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: `&msg=".urlencode(sprintf('Please use %d as otp to verify in Food App.', $otp)),`

Comment: Awesome! This worked, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
$otp  = 6547;

$msg  = "Please use '.$otp.' as otp to verify in Food App";

CURLOPT_URL => "https://sms.webpal.com.np/base/smsapi/index.php? 
            key=".$config['authkey']."&campaign=4498&routeid=22
            &type=text&contacts=".$receiver."&senderid=WebPal
            &msg=".$msg,
```